# Why is my MutableLiveData<Long> nullable?

Tags: kotlin, long-integer, nullable, mutablelivedata

I would like to know why my `elapsed` variable ends up `Long?` instead of `Long`. I defined it as not nullable and none of the operations I execute on it could result in null.

Still get the error for the last line:

```
Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'elapsed.div(1000.toLong())' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'elapsed'.
```

```
var startTime: Long = 0
var _elapsedTime = MutableLiveData<Long>(0)
_elapsedTime.value = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
val elapsed = _elapsedTime.value
val testVal = elapsed / 1000.toLong()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ends up as `Long?` because the method `LiveData.getValue()` is marked with `@Nullable` in Java.

For the interoperability between Java and Kotlin, in Kotlin that method returns a nullable `Long`, so `Long?`.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations